# Threads are leaving behind open files for TCP requests to Amazon services

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, resources, boto, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are running an application in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk using their 64bit Python container. This application spawns threads, allows them to live for a certain amount of time and then closes them before iterating through the same pattern for an arbitrary period of time.

Each of these threads then creates a few files in the Unix system - a logfile created using the logging module with a FileHandler along with various connections to SQS, EC2, Cloudwatch, Autoscale and S3 - all done using the boto module. These connections create TCP files that can be identified within the results of:

```
lsof -p {process-id}
```

When a thread finishes, we remove the FileHandler and close the logger. We also explicitly close every connection that has been made using boto. In any cases where it's possible, we create the connections or files using the `with` syntax so that any resources can (hopefully) be disposed of afterwards.

However what we are discovering is that there are TCP requests still lingering as open files on the system after the threads have been terminated - in the CLOSE_WAIT state. This is not immediately a problem but eventually the number of open files on the system exceeds the limit set in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and the Python script stops executing as a result of it.

Currently we are covering ourselves by intermittently calling the GDB and instructing it to close any handlers we've identified as being stale, but this solution lacks elegance and is ignoring the real issue which is these TCP open files continuing to linger.

Is there a pattern I'm missing here outside of the options offered to me to `close()` a connection?

Comment: `CLOSE_WAIT` can indicate that a bunch of data was "sent" to the remote side but it has not yet been received (ACKed).  What's the approximate time window that the sockets are open before you exhaust the number of open files?  And how much data is being transmitted?

Comment: Sockets are open for over half an hour at least with the last tests we ran on it. I can rerun those now in any case to check. Data being transmitted by each thread is minimal - reading approximately 100 < 5KB SQS messages and uploading 150 line text files to S3 on thread termination would sum it up.

Comment: Then what about the protocol?  Does the remote side expect more data?

Comment: All being done through HTTPS.

The SQS connection is a long poll connection. Unless you specifically ask it for data, it's not supposed to be doing anything (eg; I am the consumer of it)

With S3, we simply do our upload, it's not expecting anything more.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the same problem with sockets in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state with boto 2.3.0. The reason is that the connection is set up as follows:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
```

It will at first open a connection to find all regions, and then open a second connection to the given region. But the first connection was never closed. One can setup a ec2-connection manually through `boto.connect_ec2_endpoint(...)` or use [boto >= 2.7.0](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/27da0199ab4b74b1cd69910474702de3f100018a) 
where a static region list is used.